# Can I print until the end of the line?

Tags: bash, shell

Consider this small example:

```
printf "Loading data..."; \
sleep 5; \
echo -e "\rThis is my cool data point."
```

This brings, of course, `Loading data...`, and after 5 seconds, that will be overwritten by `This is my cool data point.`.

But what if the text printed out after the `\r` is shorter as the first line?

```
printf "Loading data..."; \
sleep 5; \
echo -e "\rNo data."
```

...brings `No data.data...` after the waiting time.

Do I have to keep track of the longest possible line and print `"\rNo data.       "` or is there any "magic character" that fills the line until its end in a normal terminal?

Comment: Yes, there is a magic character.  Try: `eol=$(tput el); printf "\rNo data.$eol\n"`

Comment: Aside from the correct solution posted by William Pursell, I would reconsider the design of your program. You are writing here to stdout - but who guarantees that your stdout indeed is connected to a terminal, and not redirected to some file? In this case you certainly don't want to have i.e. carriage return characters in the file, do you?

Comment: @user1934428 Completely right, but in this case it is a small interactive script I personally call to speed up some steps, so I can really guarantee it in this case. ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can delete to end of line with `tput el`.  So you can do:

```
eol=$(tput el)
printf "Loading data..."
sleep 5
printf "\rNo data.${eol}\n"
```

It's not really a "magic character" so much as a "magic sequence", and the actual values that are used may vary with the terminal.  `tput` will (should) do the right thing and give you a reasonably portable method.  Attempting to determine precisely which sequence to use is a futile effort.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

msg1='Loading data...'
msg2='No data.'
printf '%s' "$msg1"
sleep 5
printf '\r%*s\n' $(( -(${#msg1} > ${#msg2} ? ${#msg1} : ${#msg2}) )) "$msg2"
```

This appends trailing spaces to the line if the length of `msg1` is greater than that of `msg2`.